# "This webpage contains a blocked URL" - Can't share to FB from website under development

Tags: .htaccess

This is my first time asking a question on here, but not the first time I've been helped by the experienced folks on SO, so I'm really hoping you can help me out once again. I've seen other questions about this error on here, but it seems like they've all been about app development (or haven't been answered).

I, however, am working on a WordPress blog, not an app. It is very important that we can share our posts on our FB page, as I'm sure it is for anyone else building a blog. Although I have knowledge of basic coding, like HTML and CSS, my knowledge of more advanced web development topics is very limited, so please keep that in mind! Thanks. :)

So, as I said in my title, I get the "blocked URL" message when I put a particular post on our website through the FB debugger. When I try to share it using the share plugin on the page, I get this error: "Can't download: Could not retrieve data from URL."

I can share other posts, so I know it's not a general coding error in the site. I can also share another page with multiple audio files, so I know it's not the player. Re-uploading the audio file did not help, either. Here is the page in question:

http://brightbeams.org/3-real-dual-time-prophecies/

I saw more than one mention the .htaccess files when I was researching this problem, so I tracked mine down and copied it out below.

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule ^min/\w+\.(css|js) - [E=cache-control:no-vary]

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker MINIFY start ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/min/(\w+)\.(css|js)$
RewriteCond %1/wp-content/cache/$2/$1.$2 -f
RewriteRule min/(\w+)\.(css|js) wp-content/cache/$2/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>
### marker MINIFY end ###

## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
# END Wordfence WAF
```

I have two additional .htaccess files, so here are those as well.

```
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker MINIFY start ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/min/(\w+)\.(css|js)$
RewriteCond %1/wp-content/cache/$2/$1.$2 -f
RewriteRule min/(\w+)\.(css|js) wp-content/cache/$2/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>
### marker MINIFY end ###

## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
# END Wordfence WAF
```

---

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
# Wordfence WAF
<Files ".user.ini">
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
</Files>
# END Wordfence WAF
```

Is anyone else able to tell me where my problem lies? Or is there some other code I need to be looking at?

Thanks so much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am running into the same issue. For me it appears that my CDN is blocked, but not my actual site hence the "contains blocked url" message.

Plugging in urls to the FB debugger for my site and for the cdn I get the message:

- "This webpage contains a blocked URL." vs.
- "We can't review this website because the content doesn't meet our Community Standards. If you think this is a mistake, please let us know."

Looks like I may need to move CDNs. I'm currently on Google Cloud Storage.